# Magento 2.4.3 Paypall Express Checkout returns to a blank page (500 error)

Tags: paypal-express, magento2.4.3, amazon-web-services, amazon-payment

The order is placed and the payment goes through, but the user just sees a blank page (FF) or a generic 500 message (Chrome). When renewing the page, the message is

A successful payment transaction has already been completed. Please, check if the order has been placed.

Other payment methods are fine.

Cannot see any error messages in the payment.log

Nothing relevant I can see in system.log or exception.log

Getting some emails from Paypal about a failed payment.

How can I troubleshoot this?

upd: the apache2 log shows many errors with aws and amazon pay - can these be disabled if not used?

Comment: Are you getting _redirected from PayPal back to your store_ just before you experience this issue?

Comment: yes, to the return page with a token

Comment: @AnnaMouraviova did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have also facing same issue in my magento 2.4.2 some time paypal payments are received but order are not recorded in magento